# Hover at element which is not hoverred by mouse pointer at Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, onclick, hover

I am doing an application which the user receives a list of items to choose. When the user moves the mouse, a DIV:Hover class works backgrounding the color of the div, and when he clicks at one div to select it, an ONCLICK function marks the clicked div and redirects to a website( _blank  ). Perfect, but when you go back to this page, there is two div selected. The div user has clicked and another one. If the user moves the mouse, even if a little, the second div goes backs to normal.

What I want is to go back to the page and only the div clicked is marked.

It only happens on Google Chrome

```
Jsfiddle ---->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4ssywov/23/

```
Print Screen -->
```

http://postimg.org/image/ynr6vjdlh/

Is it possible to solve and not mark a second DIV?

If I do not redirect to a website, it works normally, but I need to redirect. =(

Comment: Another example of this bug, its easier to see JSFIDDLE -> https://jsfiddle.net/u4ssywov/72/